# Decode date on AC Delco 78S battery

Tags: battery

The date on my AC Delco 78S battery is **S082P**

When was it manufactured?  I ask because August isn't here yet so how could it be made in August?

Comment: A group with a historic steam locomotive had a similar problem... the casting said October '21 but the Baldwin warranty department was not returning their phone calls!

Answer (score 3):

The AC Delco battery date information is here:

[AC Delco Batteries](https://www.acdelco.com/content/dam/acdelco/na/us/en/index/parts/warranty/02-pdfs/acdelco-battery-warranty-information.pdf)

> How do I read the warranty date code on my battery?
> • The warranty date code is located on the top label of the battery. The first character is either a P or S. The next two digits determine the month,
> the third digit is year and the fourth digit indicates the
> manufacturing plant. For example, P 097N means the battery was made in
> September 2017.

So your S082P is: August 2002 or August 2012.  Most likely 2012.  It can't be 2022 as that is in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I have to say this is a ridiculous way to put a date on a battery. Mine shows P024R which in theory then is February either 2004 or 2014.  Since the car is a 2005 it must be 2014 again ridiculous but big thanks for the post.